# Adding a DIV dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to add a div as a dropdown to a text menu. On hovering over the text link, I'd like to have the div appear below the text, and dissapear when the user either rolls off the text, rolls off the div, (or click a link in the div, obviously). Here's the code I have so far:

I can't get the div to display at all!

Here's a jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VtXvB/

---

Viewing a local copy of my code wasn't finding the jquery library correctly (since I was using the version that is ambiguous to http:// or https://)

I fixed that, and added a "type" attribute to my script tags, and all is good.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Putting this in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would make this much easier to debug

Comment: See above! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using hover event on anchor tag, in that case unhover event occur when you move to div thats why that div became hide. So instead of your JS code use below :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menu li").hover(
    function () {
      $(this).find("a").addClass('active').next('.submenu').addClass('active').slideDown('fast');
    }, 
    function () {
      $(this).find("a").removeClass('active').next('.submenu').removeClass('active').slideUp('fast');
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: I revised the code above...but I tried referring to the li instead of the anchor tag, but still doesn't work.

Comment: @Michelle In your fiddle code you either not added the reference of jquery min file nor you specified the **display** attribute in **css** in single quote. Here is the [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VtXvB/5/)

Comment: Your demo works PERFECT, but I can't get it to work in my code. I copy/pasted it into my site and it didn't work, so I tired copy/pasting it into a totally new blank file, and it's not working. 
Here's the sample I made: http://allformyhome.com/test/test.html
And here's the original: http://allformyhome.com/test/index.html
Neither are working. I've got the link for jQuery in there, but I'm using the Google Hosted Version, does that make a difference?

Comment: I investigated the issue and found there is some special character entered in the code, please write it once again not copy paste :)